# get only integer from word using regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm not good with regular expression , so I need your help

in this below input I need to get with regular expression only integer in the last bracket from name attribute

```
<input type="text" class="redux-datepicker  group hasDatepicker" value="" name="redux_demo[17d][2]" id="g-date" data-id="g">
```

the below code will return 17 and I need 2 in the last bracket []

```
var slideCount = jQuery(newSlide).find('input[type="text"]').attr("name").match(/\d+/);
```

Comment: Do you really need a regex ? -> `slideCount.split('[').pop().replace(']','')` ... http://jsfiddle.net/bkKfZ/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To match the last occurrence you will need to use a negative lookahead. The expression you are looking for is `\d+(?!.*\d+)` which means: match a sequence of one or more numbers as long as there's no other sequence of numbers after it on the string.

On your case, this means the regexp will skip the 17 as there's at least one other number after it, but will match the 2 as it's the last number on your string.

Comment: Or you might just want to check for the end of the string with the $ meta character, which is way simpler

Comment: Yes, there are many alternatives. I went for the simplest regex that didn't include the brackets as I would have also needed to cater for chances of having things like `[17d][2c]` making the regex a little harder to follow (something that @Karl-André's solution doesn't cover, while the sample data suggests it could happen). The idea was to provide a useful base from where @Masteryo could build upon.

Comment: In the case of `[17d][2c]` it wouldn't make sense to not match the 'c', since these are array indices, so you'd have to adjust the regex anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

```
.attr("name").replace(/\[(\d+)\]$/, '$1');
```

Notice i changed `.match` with `.replace`

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to adjust your regular expression to match "(opening bracket) then  (number) then (closing bracket) then (end of string)", that is done with a regexp like this: /[\d+]$/

But since square brackets have a special meaning in regular expressions you have to escape them with "\". Furthermore you only want to capture the number itself, not the brackets, so you add round brackets around the number.

This results in the regexp /\[(\d+)\]$/

Complete line:

```
var slideCount = jQuery(newSlide).find('input[type="text"]').attr("name").match(/\[(\d+)\]$/)[1];
```

Comment: I tried your code but didn't work 
$(...).find(...).attr(...).match(...) is null

Comment: I don't know to what your newSlide Variable is set to, but my example fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrBG4/1/

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to append the [1]